# how can I read all file in a folder and compute PSNR for them using ffmpeg command as a batch file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I have some videos that I encode them to mp4 file using FFmpeg, now I need to write a batch file that read all the file in a folder and compute PSNR for them and save in separate text file for each video. I used the following code for each video, but I have to write this command for each video and the number of videos is high. do you have any suggestions for this issue?

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -i 2.mkv -lavfi psnr=stats_file=psnrmkv.txt -f null -
```

I used this code to encode all files in a folder to mp4 format:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -c:v  libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -b:v 6000K -bufsize 6000K -minrate 6000K -maxrate 6000K -x264opts keyint=120:min-keyint=120 -preset veryfast -profile:v high output\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

but I do not know how can I write some this similar for computing psnr for all video files in a folder?

Comment: Why do you need the PSNR for all the files? If you are just about to compress the files, there are other solutions out there which do a very good job at this, and do not need such difficult commands

Comment: I have to draw an R-D curve and for this, I need to compute PSNR for each video.

Comment: Sorry then I cannot help you as have no experience with PSNR computing, I only do transcoding and compressing

Comment: Thank you. the first code give me the psnr but I need a code to implement it as a loop for all videos in a folder:(